# Roughly how much more is the average salary of London compared to the north and south?

Tags: united-kingdom, salary, london

As the title states, roughly how does salary in London compare to a job in the south (say, Bristol), versus a job in the north (say, Leeds)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trust in the [Pedia!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_in_the_United_Kingdom) and if you don't believe them, then their [source](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/stats/income_distribution/table3-11-2004-05.pdf) which is HM Government.

The numbers are regional instead of by city, and are mean averages.

For your three areas:
London  £29,947

Yorkshire (including Leeds I believe)   £20,247

South West England (which would include Bristol; but also all of Cornwall) 
£20,954

A more industry specific query might have significantly different results.

Comment: Ooh, interesting, I would have expected a difference between yorkshire and the south west of England. My specific area is IT, software engineering (.NET development).

Comment: There may well be a bigger difference if you can find the stats for city-to-city, instead of region vs. region.  Programming salaries also tend to be a little different than a general average.

Comment: Southwest is quite depressed area for the locals

Answer (score 3):

The average salary in London is almost certainly going to be higher, when I was looking for a new job it was anything from 5k-10k higher in London than it was in East Anglia.

Don't be fooled by the higher salary, if I would take pursued a city job I'd be losing several thousand per year on commuting, not to mention time as well. Thats not mentioning relocating closer to the city, that would be more expensive.

You have to weigh it up, is the salary really going to compensate the commute/living costs?

Comment: And development salaries are a lot more around £50k for central London